# VS 2013 marking code in blue outline?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide

What's going on with this? I've never seen it before and have no idea how to turn this on or off. It doesn't do it with any other block of js code (or other code, for that matter). If I could get it to do this with every single block of code, that would be more than incredible...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong then most probably that's the code block where you have `debug point/break point` set to and so it's highlighting the same area. At least, that's what it does for `C#` editor; hopefully will be the same for `Jquery` as well.

To turn it off, remove the break point and see if it still remains.

Comment: Turning off the breakpoint removes it but putting it back doesn't bring back the highlighting. It colors it red, for sure, but not just blue highlighting. I suppose maybe just a glitch? I was really hoping it would highlight code blocks like that for me.

Comment: It generally happens when you have a disabled breakpoint and it does do code block highlight.

Comment: I am not sure if VS by itself has any code block highlighting for normal cases but you can try `Re-Sharper` for the same purpose though.

Comment: Holy. Crap. I need to install that. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, check Slaks blog once; looks interesting to me http://blog.slaks.net/2013-12-10/syntax-highlighted-markdown-code-blocks-web-essentials/. Again, first get a `Re-sharper` license :).